# How to get a cell that contains a specific value using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to get a single item that contains a string within a single column along with its row position.

im using the following to find the item within the column :

```
match = dataFrame[column].str.fullmatch(keyToMatch)
```

This works great in retrieving the boolean value of all comparisons. However, I'd only like to retrieve a single `True` value. I've gone through the documentation and I've found methods such a `drop()`, however that method only applies to the index of the returned series. How do I go through the values and drop all `False` values from a series?

Comment: If you drop all the False values, you will be left with one `True`, which I assume is not what you want.  Can you show the desired output you are looking for?  Also, can you define 'row position'.  Do you mean the column number (0 to n)?

Comment: You can use `dataframe.query('@column.str.fullmatch(@keytoMatch)')` to only return the relevant entries.

Comment: Also, please define what you mean by "item that contains a string". For example, the string "abcde" contains "bcd". Is this what you mean? Is `keyToMatch` a regular expression, or just a string?  it's hard to tell when you don't provide any example values.

Answer (score 1):

`match = dataFrame[column].str.fullmatch(keyToMatch)` will create a boolean Series.

If you are sure that you have at least one `True`, you can get the first `True` index with `idx = match.idxmax()` and the value with `val = dataFrame.loc[idx, column]`

If you're not sure that there is at least one `True`, rather use `idx = check[check].index[:1]`